# Create a sitemap.xml programmatically for a multi-language / multi-domain site on the fly

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, xml-sitemap

**Note:** this is not about how do sitemaps work, or how a sitemap structure looks like, neither a SEO related issue.

My domains **mysite.com** and **mysite.pt** are 2 language versions (EN, PT) of the same site.
The content is added/removed dynamically via a db-driven CMS.

Each menu/category update creates its language specific routes, e.g: **mysite.com/beach** and **mysite.pt/praia**, where both create a route pointing to the same controller e.g. `site_manager/page/beaches`.

The codebase for each language version is identical, hence there is only one /application, /assets and /system folder for all language versions.
The [language specific content](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html) is loaded via `<?=$this->lang->line('my_token1')?>`

The file system looks like:

```
/public_html
    /mysite.com/index.php
    /mysite.pt/index.php
    /all_sites/application
    /all_sites/assets
    /all_sites/system
```

The index.php file in both site’s route directory [changes system and application folder location](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html#relocating-your-application-directory):

```php
$system_path = '/home/my_host/public_html/all_sites/system';
$application_folder = '/home/my_host/public_html/all_sites/application';
```

This setup works smoothly.
But the CMS is old and doesn't create an updated sitemap whenever menu or content is changed.

So I thought about another way to provide an updated site/language-specific `sitemap.xml`:
When the bots come scanning the site, the sitemap could be created on the fly and provide the bot with the most updated `sitemap.xml`

I resolved this by creating a controller method `site_manager/sitemap()` which parses the database entries and outputs a sitemap with `echo $this->load->view('sitemap',$data,true);`

which outputs, depending on the site:

```xml
<!-- created by mysite.pt, 2020-12-22 -->
<url>
  <loc>https:// mysite.pt/</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-12-22T20:53:36+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https:// mysite.pt/praias.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-12-22T19:51:51+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

Or

```xml
<!-- created by mysite.com, 2020-12-22 -->
<url>
  <loc>https:// mysite.com/</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-12-22T20:53:36+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https:// mysite.com/beaches.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-12-22T19:51:51+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

**The question:**
The problem with this setup is that I won’t have any sitemap.xml in the root directory, as there is only an echoed output, once the controller function was used. The bots will go home empty handed, because of not finding any sitemap.xml, same if you type mysite.com/sitemap.xml.

How can I make the bot to access the controller method and consequently read the generated output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bots are looking for the `sitemap.xml` in the site’s root.

To make a bot “read” the controller’s echoed output, it needs to be directed to the controller function, in our case to `site_manager/sitemap()`.

The trick is to make a .htaccess redirect towards the controller which creates the sitemap output, note `site_manager` is set as the default controller in routes.php:

**redirect sitemap.xml to sitemap.php**

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

This means the bot which is trying to read the “non existing sitemap.xml” is redirected to the controller and fed via `echo $this->load->view('sitemap',$data,true);`
with the output of the dynamic sitemap data on the fly, getting the most up-to-date sitemap xml data possible.

You can test the successful sitemap creation, Typing e.g.   `https://mysite.pt/sitemap.xml`  in your browser:

Note: you won’t find above created sitemap.xml file in your ftp directory listing of `ftp://mysite.pt` ! , since this file was never written or uploaded.

You can also verify through the search consoles of the mayor directory listings like google, bing, etc. and confirm if a sitemap was submitted successfully by the bypassing bot